# How to add html content to maven site generated by the maven site plugin?

Tags: pom.xml, markup, apt, maven-site-plugin

I am using the maven site plugin to generate a project site. This creates a default site and can be viewed under src/target/index.html. I need to add content to the index. How can this be done?

ON reading the maven documentation, I created an index.apt under the src/site folder. How do I get the content of this file to show up in the index.html page in the target folder?

Answer (score 2):

I am using Maven 3.3.9
My solution was to add an index.html file under ${baseDir}/src/site/resources.
Then run:

```
mvn clean site
```

Your index.html file should replace the default one.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to launch `mvn clean site`.